# PHP SQL declare YES or NO based on count withing query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching for a way to make the sql statement declare a AS example as Yes when the value is greater than 0 and No if 0 after I count the result while retreiving the data from the database.

This (is not working) is what I tried so far. I hope my tryout is making sence. I first make a select count on `planning_clientid` the result is 0 or more. If the result is 0 I need `timesonplanning` (perhaps change that name after its working) to be `No` and if higher than `Yes`. So in steady of the count result I need Yes or No, Is this possible?

Part that is not working:

```
(CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(planning_clientid) FROM tbl_planning WHERE planning_afgehandeld = 0 AND a.client_id = planning_clientid)> 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS timesonplanning
```

The whole statement:

```
   SELECT a.*, own1.naam AS resposible_btw, own2.naam AS resposible_client, (CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(planning_clientid) FROM tbl_planning WHERE planning_afgehandeld = 0 AND a.client_id = planning_clientid)> 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS timesonplanning FROM tbl_clients a LEFT JOIN gebruikers own1 ON own1.id = a.client_ownerob LEFT JOIN gebruikers own2 ON own2.id = a.client_owner
```

Desired result:

timesonplanning Yes (when count if higher than 0)
timesonplanning No (when count is 0)

Comment: Simply stating “*This (is not working)*” isn’t a particularly helpful problem statement. What isn’t working about it? Is there an error message when you try to run this? If so, why haven’t you included it here? What do you expect to happen, and where are you getting stuck? Can you include a sample of the data that’s in your table currently (to provide some assurance that the issue isn’t with the data itself)? We aren’t clairvoyant. Include all relevant debugging details in the body of your question, per [ask] and ensure your code and sample data conforms to [mre].

Comment: Thanks for you reaction. Sorry for my way of asking. The statement i posted is not working, this part: (CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(planning_clientid) FROM tbl_planning WHERE planning_afgehandeld = 0 AND a.client_id = planning_clientid)> 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS timesonplanning. I am simply searching for a way to make the yes or no happend after counting

Comment: I get that, you stated that in your question; *how* is it not working? The term “*not working*” can be used to describe a number of scenarios in software development, and we can’t guess exactly what’s wrong with it without you telling us. As I asked, can you elaborate on how exactly it’s not working? Is there an error message? Does it simply not function the way you expect? What does your data look like?

Comment: I tried to change the question. I get the Error: #1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij 'AS timesonplanning FROM tbl_clients a LEFT JOIN gebruikers own1 ON own1.id = ...' in regel 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you indicated in the comments indicates a syntax error (albeit in Dutch). This is indeed to be expected as the query you included doesn’t close the initial parenthesis character `(` you used right before your `CASE` keyword.

Resolve this by removing the initial parenthesis before `CASE` (as it doesn’t seem particularly necessary in this context), or properly close it by inserting a close parenthesis `)` after the `END` keyword:

```
SELECT a.*, own1.naam AS resposible_btw, own2.naam AS resposible_client, (CASE WHEN(SELECT COUNT(planning_clientid) FROM tbl_planning WHERE planning_afgehandeld = 0 AND a.client_id = planning_clientid)> 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS timesonplanning FROM tbl_clients a LEFT JOIN gebruikers own1 ON own1.id = a.client_ownerob LEFT JOIN gebruikers own2 ON own2.id = a.client_owner
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and I am sorry for my poor way of asking !